# How to set environment variables in fish shell script

Tags: fish

In my fish shell script 'hoge.fish`, I have a code to set envs.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish
set -x HOGE "hello"
```

but after I exec this script the env is not set correctly and outputs nothing.

```
./hoge.fish
echo $HOGE
```

I've tried these code but none of these worked.

```
set -gx HOGE "hello"
set -gU HOGE "hello"
```

how can I fix this?

- OS: macOS High Sierra `10.13.6`
- fish version:  `2.7.1`
- iTerm2: `3.2.0`

Comment: I ran `./hoge.fish` and `echo $HOGE`

Comment: Use -Ux option instead

Answer (score 5):

When you ran the script, it probably set the environment variable correctly, but only in the process that was created when you ran the script....*not* in the parent session you ran the script from!   When the script exited, the process and its environment were destroyed.

If you want to change the environment variable in your current environment, depending on what interactive shell you're using, you can use a command like `source hoge.fish`, which will execute the commands in your current session rather than a subprocess, so the environment variable changes will persist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to make a cli with fish script, so I am planing to `cp hoge.fish /usr/local/bin` in the future and I am worring how I can run like `source hoge.fish`? I want to use like a command, for example , `$ hoge` in the terminal. Or is it impossible to change enviromental variable by script?

Comment: It is impossible.

Comment: It's not impossible, you only need to export it not globally but universally :D, try -Ux option

Answer (score 1):

While `source`ing, as in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682432/11810933) is definitely the correct mechanism, a comment from the OP to that answer mentioned that they would still prefer a solution that could be executed as a script.

As long as the variables are exported (`set -x`) in the script, it's *possible* (but still not necessarily recommended) to do this by `exec`ing into another fish shell inside the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fish
set -gx HOGE hello
exec fish
```

Executing `./hoge.fish` will then have a fish shell with `HOGE` set as expected.

However, be aware:

- This will result in two fish shell processes running, one inside the other.  The first (parent) is the original fish shell.  It will spawn a second (child) process based on the shebang line, which will then be *replaced* by the third instance from the `exec` line.
- You can reduce the number of shells that are running simultaneously by starting the script with `exec ./hoge.fish`.  That results in the shebang script *replacing* the parent process, and then being replaced by the `exec` line at the end of the script.  However, you will still have run fish's startup *twice* to achieve what a simple `source` would have done with *zero* additional startups.
- It's also important to realize the environment of the new shell will *not* necessarily be the same as that of the original shell.  In particular, local variables from the original shell will not be present in the `exec`'d shell.

There are use-cases where these pitfalls are worth `exec`ing a new shell, but most of the time a simple `source` will be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that if you run that from bash shell it will not export the variables with the -U option because it indicates to export to "fish universe" not outside.

If you stay inside fish's shell you still can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish
set -Ux HOGE "hello"
```

And this is the result:

```
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
~/trash $ ./hoge.fish
~/tr ash $ echo $HOGE
hello
```

Remember to keep the first line so fish will interpret it properly.

Comment: While I'm a huge fan of fish's universal variables, they *really* aren't the right solution here.  Universal variables in fish will update in *all* running shell instances, which may have unintended side-effects.  The correct method is to `source` the file, rather than execute it, as the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682432/11810933) states.  This is a standard shell technique that will work not only in fish,, but also bash, zsh, and most others.

Comment: I think you're right, it is a workaround because it looks universal and global variables has conflicts while working together in fish link https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/6218 

Comment: Right - Use universals when you (a) really are sure that the value should be the same *everywhere*, and (b) are aware of the possible conflicts with globals (which can be used to properly override the universal, but can make debugging issues more difficult if you aren't looking for the global/universal clash).  For this particular question, I'd recommend sticking with globals that are `source`d.